# Can np.load command load a file from some other directory?

Tags: python-2.7

I am unable to understand the purpose of this command. I have looked for command np.load but it is not giving any information about directory. I will be thankful if you please explain this or suggest some link to understand this command.
    `TRAIN_set = np.load(train_dir+'/train_set.npy')`

Answer (score 1):

`np.load` is not doing anything with a directory, here.

When used with strings, the `+` operator concatenates them. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) (emphasis mine):

> The + (addition) operator yields the sum of its arguments. The
>   arguments must either both be numbers or both sequences of the same
>   type. In the former case, the numbers are converted to a common type
>   and then added together. **In the latter case, the sequences are
>   concatenated.**

So this: `train_dir+'/train_set.npy'`is merely concatenating a directory name with a file name to give the full path to load from.

Comment: So if two folders are on Desktop having two folders. And I save a file using np.save in one folder but I have to load it in other folder. Can np.load command load the file save in other folder?

Comment: They can load an save from wherever you tell them to. You just pass in the string containing the full path.